# DNS query over TCP

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, dns

What I have now is DNS query over UDP and it's working properly, but if message is truncated and i need to reconnect over TCP with the same query i can't do that, main problem is that i do have query in byte array and tcp sends chars.

My assembling of UDP query:

```
String DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS = args[0];
    String domain = args[1];
    ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

    // *** Build a DNS Request Frame ****

    // Identifier: A 16-bit identification field generated by the device that creates the DNS query.
    // It is copied by the server into the response, so it can be used by that device to match that
    // query to the corresponding reply received from a DNS server. This is used in a manner similar
    // to how the Identifier field is used in many of the ICMP message types.
    dos.writeShort(0x1234);

    // Write Query Flags
    dos.writeShort(0x0100);

    // Question Count: Specifies the number of questions in the Question section of the message.
    dos.writeShort(0x0001);

    // Answer Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Answer section of the message.
    dos.writeShort(0x0000);

    // Authority Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Authority section of
    // the message. (“NS” stands for “name server”)
    dos.writeShort(0x0000);

    // Additional Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Additional section of the message.
    dos.writeShort(0x0000);

    // TODO: write query
    String[] domainParts = domain.split("\\.");
    System.out.println(domain + " has " + domainParts.length + " parts");

    for (String domainPart : domainParts) {
        System.out.println("Writing: " + domainPart);
        byte[] domainBytes = domainPart.getBytes("UTF-8");
        dos.writeByte(domainBytes.length);
        dos.write(domainBytes);
    }

    // No more parts
    dos.writeByte(0x00);

    // QType 0x01 = A (Host Request)
    if (args.length>2)
        dos.writeShort(typeEncode(args[2]));
    else
        dos.writeShort(0x00ff); // "ANY" as default

    // QClass 0x01 = IN
    dos.writeShort(0x0001);

    dnsFrame = baos.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("Sending: " + dnsFrame.length + " bytes");
    for (byte aDnsFrame : dnsFrame) {
        System.out.print("0x" + String.format("%x", aDnsFrame) + " ");
    }

    // *** Send DNS Request Frame ***
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    DatagramPacket dnsReqPacket = new DatagramPacket(dnsFrame, dnsFrame.length, ipAddress, DNS_SERVER_PORT);
    socket.send(dnsReqPacket);
    return socket;
```

How I try to send it over TCP:

```
Socket echoSocket = null;
    // strumień do zapisu do serwera
    Writer out = null;
    // strumień do odczytu z serwera
    BufferedReader in = null;
    // nazwa serwera
    String hostname=args[0];

    try {
        System.out.println("próba utworzenia gniazda");
        echoSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, DNS_SERVER_PORT);
        System.out.println("próba utworzenia strumienia wyjściowego");
        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        OutputStream outputStream = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("próba utworzenia strumienia wejściowego");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));


        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
        os.flush();
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());
        os.writeObject(dnsFrame);
        byte[] temp = (byte[]) is.readObject();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Nieznany host: " + hostname + ".");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Błąd połączenia z " + hostname + ".");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    // zakończenie pracy - pozamykaj strumienie i gniazda
    out.close();
    in.close();
    echoSocket.close();
```

I used wireshark to read what I actually send in TCP and it is not the same as UDP so i assume problem is in process of sending byte array.

Comment: _"tcp sends chars"_ -- what makes you think this is true?  an `ObjectOutputStream` is intended for Java objects, and is very different from a `DataOutputStream`.  Your TCP and UDP versions are very different from each other.

Comment: TCP sends *octets*. You should not be using `Readers` and `Writers`, you should be using the same `DataInput/OutputStream` as you are with YDP, indeed very much the same code but with `Socket.getInput/OutputStream()` as the underlying stream rather than the `ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DNS's TCP protocol is the same as its UDP protocol with one difference - the messages sent over TCP are prefixed by a 16-bit integer in network byte order to specify the message byte length.  That is not required over UDP as the message lengths are determined by the size of the datagrams.

Per [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), "DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION":

> 4.2. Transport
>
> The DNS assumes that messages will be transmitted as datagrams or in a
> byte stream carried by a virtual circuit.  While virtual circuits can be
> used for any DNS activity, datagrams are preferred for queries due to
> their lower overhead and better performance.  Zone refresh activities
> must use virtual circuits because of the need for reliable transfer.
>
> The Internet supports name server access using TCP [RFC-793] on server
> port 53 (decimal) as well as datagram access using UDP [RFC-768] on UDP
> port 53 (decimal).
>
> 4.2.1. UDP usage
>
> Messages sent using UDP user server port 53 (decimal).
>
> Messages carried by UDP are restricted to 512 bytes (not counting the IP
> or UDP headers).  Longer messages are truncated and the TC bit is set in
> the header.
>
> UDP is not acceptable for zone transfers, but is the recommended method
> for standard queries in the Internet.  Queries sent using UDP may be
> lost, and hence a retransmission strategy is required.  Queries or their
> responses may be reordered by the network, or by processing in name
> servers, so resolvers should not depend on them being returned in order.
>
> The optimal UDP retransmission policy will vary with performance of the
> Internet and the needs of the client, but the following are recommended:
>
> - The client should try other servers and server addresses before repeating a query to a specific address of a server.
> - The retransmission interval should be based on prior statistics if possible.  Too aggressive retransmission can easily slow responses for the community at large.  Depending on how well connected the client is to its expected servers, the minimum retransmission interval should be 2-5 seconds.
>
> More suggestions on server selection and retransmission policy can be
> found in the resolver section of this memo.
>
> 4.2.2. TCP usage
>
> Messages sent over TCP connections use server port 53 (decimal).  **The
> message is prefixed with a two byte length field which gives the message length, excluding the two byte length field.  This length field allows
> the low-level processing to assemble a complete message before beginning
> to parse it**.
>
> Several connection management policies are recommended:
>
> - The server should not block other activities waiting for TCP data.
> - The server should support multiple connections.
> - The server should assume that the client will initiate connection closing, and should delay closing its end of the connection until all outstanding client requests have been satisfied.
> - If the server needs to close a dormant connection to reclaim resources, it should wait until the connection has been idle for a period on the order of two minutes.  In particular, the server should allow the SOA and AXFR request sequence (which begins a refresh operation) to be made on a single connection. Since the server would be unable to answer queries anyway, a unilateral close or reset may be used instead of a graceful close.

So, all you have to do in TCP is:

1. connect your TCP socket to the DNS server
2. when sending a DNS query, create your message byte array the **exact same way** you are in UDP, then send the byte array's length as a 16-bit integer before sending the byte array itself.
3. when reading a DNS response, read the 16-bit length first and then read the number of bytes it specifies.
4. repeat steps 2-3 as needed for however many queries you need to send.
5. close the connection when finished.

Also see:

[RFC 7766: DNS Transport over TCP - Implementation Requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7766)

In short, DO NOT use I/O classes that are based on string characters, objects, etc, like you are currently trying to do.  DNS messages are binary data, and are formatted the exact same way in UDP and TCP.  Your code to generate and parse DNS messages should be exactly the same regardless of which transport you use.  The only thing that is different is how you transmit/receive the raw message bytes:

- use `DatagramSocket` and `DatagramPacket` in UDP.
- use `Socket`, `OutputStream`, and `InputStream` in TCP.  You can use [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to help you, where:
- [`DataOutputStream.writeShort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeShort(int)) and [`DataOutpuStream.write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) can be used for sending a message
- [`DataInputStream.readShort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readShort()) (or [`readUnsignedShort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUnsignedShort())) and [`DataInputStream.readFully()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully(byte%5B%5D)) can be used for reading a message.